# jquery mobile form value prints as text

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with a form and jQuery Mobile.

I have a select:

```
<div id="search-cat-box" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <select name="cat">
        <option value="all">Search all categories</option>
            {foreach from=$catlist key=k item=i name=cat_list}
               <option value="{$i.catid}">{$i.category}</option>
            {/foreach}
    </select>
</div>
```

When I look at the form in my browser it outputs the value also as text to the left of the selectbox like this:

```
Search all categories <option>Search all categories</option>
```

Same problem with the submit button

```
Search <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search-submit">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What other js libraries are you using?

Comment: only jQuery... changed the loading order and voila! 
Will you place an answer? Your comment showed me were to look!

Comment: go ahead and do it yourself, I did nothing honestly =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changed in the loading order of jQuery and jQuery Mobile